# Setting Band Statistics on Raster Image (GeoTIFF)

Tags: python, gdal, statistics

After doing calculations on a raster and saving it, the image statistics are wrong and need updating.

I find examples saying that this should do the job, like [in this example](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_hw5b.py):

```
 dsband.WriteArray(data)
 dsband.FlushCache()
 dsband.GetStatistics(0,1)
```

However this does not seem to update my band statistics correctly, they seem ok in Python with data.max() and data.min(), but opening the file in QuantumGis (image properties>style>load min/max) shows the wrong stats. I only get new image statistics correctly by separately opening and setting statistics like this:

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
driver.Register()
ds = gdal.Open(infile, gdal.GA_Update)
dsband = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
(newmin, newmax)= dsband.ComputeRasterMinMax(0)
(newmean, newstdv) = dsband.ComputeBandStats(1)
dsband.SetStatistics(newmin, newmax,newmean, newstdv)
dsband.FlushCache()       
dsband = None  
ds = None
```

So what's the difference between both and why does QGis only show the correct stats with the second code?

thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works for me (in that QGis reads the statistics correctly). Note use of ComputeStatistics instead of GetStatistics as that will force gdal to recalculate band statistics.

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff' )
dst_ds = driver.Create( dst_filename, 512,512, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16 )
raster = somenumpy.calculation(etc...)
rb=dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
rb.WriteArray( raster )
rb.ComputeStatistics(0)
dst_ds = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where there were differences between statistics in Python and QGIS for the same tile/data. I'm rather new to this so I can't offer an explanation as to why but I managed to get the correct values displayed in QGIS by going to properties > symbology > Min/Max value settings and then setting 'Accuracy' to 'Actual (slower)'.